# Highstock datetime xAxis, can only show all. no zoom

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I have made a high stock chart with data from json.

My problem is that I can only see my data when I zoom out completely.
When I zoom in on a week or month, the data in the chart disappears.

I can still see the data in the navigator window at the bottom.

JSON:

```
[
[1475452800000, '10.69'],
[1475193600000, '10.86'],
[1475107200000, '10.69'],
[1475020800000, '10.91']
... (aprox a year)
]
```

Java:

```
$.getJSON('_json_stock.php?InfoHistory=<?php echo $G_CompanyStockSymbol;?>', function (data) {

// create the chart data: data,
$('#stockChartHistory').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },          
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [
            {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            },, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
            },, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }           
        ],
        selected: 2
        },
        series: [{
        name: '<?php echo $G_CompanyStockSymbol;?>',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2                
        },          
        threshold: null
        }]
});
```

});

Comment: fiddle or live example?

Comment: Yes sorry: [link]http://kristjanwestberg.dk/stockvalue/test.php[/link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in your console, you'll see that Highcharts is outputting error code 15

```
Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15
```

Reference:

- http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15

> Highcharts expects data to be sorted
>
> This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock
>   chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For
>   performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is
>   required that the implementer pre-sorts the data.

If the data is not in order by x value, things will not work properly. You'll have to sort the data before sending it to the chart.

Comment: console is part of your browser - how to access it depends on which browser/extensions you are using.